# Overriding default GORM id generator

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In GORM, it is possible for someone to specify the default id generator in config.groovy by doing:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator : 'uuid2', type: 'pg-uuid'
}
```

However, I have a class in a plugin which is expecting the id to be a long, so it falls over.  I could change the plugin, but just wondering if I have any other options here?

Thanks

Comment: Somehow you would have to exclude the domain from being affected by the new id mapping default. Ideally, when a plugin uses a domain class, and that usage assumes the id for the domain is a Long, then the plugin should be explicit about the id for that domain always being a Long (setting id Long in the mapping definition of the domain). If done this way, the domain id would not be changed with a new global id mapping setting like this I don't think. Changing the default uuid might be overkill, Long *might* be all you need, see https://rclayton.silvrback.com/do-you-really-need-a-uuid-guid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing an AST Transformation on the domain classes of your project which would convert any Long fields to String fields.

Grails scans the package `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler` for any classes which implement [grails.compiler.ast.GrailsArtefactClassInjector](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/compiler/ast/GrailsArtefactClassInjector.html).  Create a  class in this package which scans domain classes and removes any `id` properties which have a class of `Long` and replaces them with a property of class `String` (or whatever class type you need).